# $a_n>0, n\in\mathbb Z, \lim_{n->\infty}\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}}=0$, show that $\{a_n\}$ is unbounded.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I tried to proof it by contradiction.
I assume $\{a_n\}$ is bounded, then there exists $M$ such that $a_n<M$. Therefore
$$
\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}}>\frac{a_n}{2M}>0
$$

which implies $\lim_{n->\infty}a_n=0$. However I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try it the following way:

If $\lim\limits_{n->\infty}\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}}=0$ then there exists some $N$ so that $\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}}<\frac{1}{4}$ for all $n\geq N$.

This means that $a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}>4{a_n}$ for all $n\geq N$.

This however means that $a_{n+1}>2a_n$ and/or $a_{n+2}>2a_n$.

Now we can prove via recursion that there must be at least one element $a_k>2^ma_N$ in the range $N<k\leq(N+2m)$.

Now prove that $2^ma_N$ is unbounded for $m\to\infty$.